# Reading the values out of an expression string, while keeping the formula intact

Tags: c#, string, operators

I have some code with mathematical operations, and I'm trying to make them easier to read and debug. But a very particular case is becoming complex, here's an example:

```cs
public int val1=1;
public int val2=2;
public int val3=3;
public int val4=4;

public int operation(int argA, int argB)
{
    int val = argA+argB;
    return val;
}
```

Then I have the following conditional:

```cs
if (operation((val1+val2), val2) + val3 >= val4)
{

    //do stuff

}
```

What I'm aiming to do is use "(operation((val1+val2), val2) + val3 >= val4)" as a string, and convert into a more readable formula, while ignoring the insides of operation().

Example:

```cs
string str = "(operation((val1+val2), val2) + val3 >= val4)";
```

A method would read str, and return the following string:

```cs
"(operation() + 3 >= 4)"
```

Getting the values is easy with the method ahead:
But the real aim is to be able to detect the parenthesis, and basically replace the substring "operation((val1+val2), val2)", that can have different variable names than val1 and val2, with something else.

Where is what I've done so far to make this accessible:

```cs
//A method

public string mathstringtest(string arg_msg)
{

    List<string> msglist = new List<string>();
    //a set of arrays to help me take care of the different elements that can come up in a string
    string[] variablefilter = { "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", };
    string[] ignorefilter = { "operation()" }; //I want to use this to ignore all the contents of operation method in the string.. but I don't know how to do it, and I have multiple parenthesis inside the original "operation((val1+val2), val2)"
    string[] operatorfilter = { "+", "-", "/", "*", "<", ">", "<=", ">=", "&&", "||" };

    string msg = "";
    int i = 0;
    //split the string into different elements, every operator and parenthesis get its own place
    string[] dates = Regex.Split(arg_msg, @"([*()\^\/]|(?<!E)[\+\-])");

    foreach (string sum in dates)
    {
    //removes empty spaces
        dates[i] = Regex.Replace(sum, @"\s+", "");
        i++;
    }


    int sumflag;
    //from below it starts sorting, acting on what to ignore, what to consider, etc
    foreach (string sum in dates)
    {
        sumflag = 0;
        if (!ignorefilter.Contains(sum))
        {

            if (operatorfilter.Contains(sum))
            {
                msglist.Add(sum + " ");
                sumflag = 1;

            }
            foreach (string filter in variablefilter)
            {

                if (sum.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()))
                {
                    //this is a special method that triages the variables of the string into int, double, etc
                    msglist.Add(mathstringtriagetest(sum, filter));
                    sumflag = 1;

                }
            }
            if (sumflag == 0)
            {
                msglist.Add(sum);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (string str in msglist)
    {
        msg += str;

    }
    return msg;
}
```

```cs
//The special method for triage:
public string mathstringtriagetest(string sum, string filter)
{
    string msg = "";
    List<string> msglist = new List<string>();
    try
    {

        double test = (double)this.GetType().GetField(sum).GetValue(this);

        msglist.Add(test.ToString());
        
    }
    catch
    {

        try
        {
            int test = (int)this.GetType().GetField(sum).GetValue(this);
            msglist.Add(test.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            string test = filter;
            msglist.Add(test);
        }

    }
    foreach (string str in msglist)
    {
        msg += str;

    }
    return msg;
}
```

```cs
string test = "(val1 + 20 / val2 - 5))";
```

I call mathstring(test); and voila.. This works fine, but I cannot "detect" and act upon a method in the string like `operation((val1+val2), val2)`

The problem I have is ignoring the contents of a method inside a mathematical operation
I want to be able to detect this in the string:

```
operation((val1+val2), val2)
```

Regardless of the val1 and val2 variable names

I'm doing a lot of things at the same time that could be more efficient probably, like the triage method, I suspect that nobody will have time to read through this, but if you do thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This will effectivelly count the parenthesis and replace the whole math method by something different

```
        string workstr = arg_msg;
        //p(arg_msg);
        string[,] methods = { {"ratio(", "ratio__UP(" },

        { static_msgRatio, static_msgRatio__UP,


        { "static_msgRatio", "static_msgRatio__UP"}
        };

        int strLength = arg_msg.Length;
        int counter;
        int startpos;
        int startposaux=0;
        int endpos;
        int a;
        for (int k = 0; k < methods.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            //p("-----"+ methods[0, k]);
            if (arg_msg.Contains(methods[0, k]))
            {
                do
                {
                    counter = 1;
                    startpos = arg_msg.IndexOf(methods[0, k], startposaux, strLength - startposaux);

                    //p(startpos);
                    //p(arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[0,k].Length));
                    //p(arg_msg[startpos + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[k, 0].Length).Length]);
                    //p(arg_msg[startpos + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[k, 0].Length).Length + 1]);
                    //p(arg_msg[startpos + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[k, 0].Length).Length + 2]);
                    a = startpos;
                    endpos = startpos;

                    
                    do
                    {

                        // p(arg_msg[a]);
                        // p(arg_msg[a + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[k, 0].Length).Length]);
                        if (arg_msg[a + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[0, k].Length).Length] == '(')
                        {
                            //p("Y");
                            // p(arg_msg[a + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[k, 0].Length).Length]);
                            counter++;
                        }
                        else if (arg_msg[a + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[0, k].Length).Length] == ')')
                        {
                            //p("N");
                            counter--;
                        }

                        endpos = a + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[0, k].Length).Length - startpos + 1;
                        startposaux = a + arg_msg.Substring(startpos, methods[0, k].Length).Length;
                        a++;

                    }

                    while (counter > 0 && a < strLength);
                    //p(a + " " + (strLength - startpos));
                    //p(startpos + " " + endpos);
                    //p(arg_msg);
                    p(arg_msg.Substring(startpos, endpos));
                    //p(methods[2, k]);
                    workstr = workstr.Replace(arg_msg.Substring(startpos, endpos), methods[2, k]);
                    p(workstr);
                    //p(startposaux);
                } while (arg_msg.IndexOf(methods[0, k], startposaux, strLength - startposaux) != -1);
                startposaux = 0;
            }
        } 
        arg_msg = workstr;
```